# How to quote Fieldnames in Fluent NHibernate 1.1

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

After upgrading from Fluent NHibernate 1.0 RTM to 1.1 I got some strange errors when creating the database. After some investigation I discovered that FNH 1.0 quoted all field names in the generated mapping files like 'user', but FNH 1.1 did not. This results in errors for the generated sql script when I use restriced keywords for properties.

Is it somehow possible to reactivate this feature of FNH 1.0 or enable quoting otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the code that is generated and sent to the sql server or the psedo mappings files it generates?

Comment: I'd hassard a guess that this is the way it should be. Since each database has its own quote character, in Sql its [ and ] in MySql its ` and `.
So its right that escaping or quoting isn't in the mapping files. it's determined at runtime depending the driver you've configured.

I think your looking in the wrong place. Look into why the driver you've selected isn't quoting correctly. IE check you've selected the correct driver to match the db capabilities.